# Does loading unneed models in controller constructor affect performance in CodeIgniter 2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Which one is better performance-wise? Loading all the models used in the controller in constructor or loading the model only in the needed function? Or is there any difference? If the model is needed only in one of the functions of a big controller, does it affect the performance if its loaded in the constructor?

```
class myController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('loginmodel');
    }

    public function useLoginModel(){
        $this->load->model('loginmodel');
        $this->loginmodel->login();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only use it in that one function, then it is probably faster to load it only there. But this decreases mantainability. You always have to recheck if the model was loaded every time you want to use it somewhere. So I would stick with loading everything in the constructor (depends on the number of models obviously).

There is a simple rule for optimizations: If it isn't slow, don't optimize it. You gain very little from the above change, but encounter a severe hit in mantainability (or as symfony calls it "Developer Experience")

Answer (score -2):

You can add it in autoload.php inside config folder.

```
$autoload['model'] = array('loginmodel');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: If you are using multiple models then its better to load it in respective functions and if there is only only one function then auto load it. But anyhow the difference will be less.